# Why is there is a space added to make string in JTextArea after a KeyListener?

Tags: java

First off I making a simple typing program. If you type the a letter and hit the spacebar the TTextArea will be matched with the label text to see if it matches. But it keeps coming out wrong cause there is space added before the letter after the first output everytime and I do not understand why? Is this something that just happens or can ypu

The is my code

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
 if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    input = textArea.getText();
    if(input.length() <= 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type something first");
    } else {
        input.trim();
        System.out.println(input);
        gameLogic.score(input, letterLabel.getText());
        gameLogic.error(input, letterLabel.getText());
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(gameLogic.score));
        errorLabel.setText("Errors: " + String.valueOf(gameLogic.error));
        gameLogic.changeDifficulty();
        letterLabel.setText( gameLogic.changeText());
        textArea.setText("");
        textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
    }
}
```

this is my output

```
   l
    l
    x
    k
    ss
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things...

`KeyListener` is not a recommend way to deal with monitoring or effecting the changes to any text component.  If you are lucky enough that the key stroke isn't consumed by the component, the component has already being updated with the last key stroke.

A better approach would be to use a `DocumentListener` if you just wanted to monitor changes to the text component or a `DocumentFilter` if you want to change what is being passed to the field.

Check out [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for more details